# Strange way of statistical analysis_Need some advice

Tags: ancova

I have a question regarding the project which I am doing now.

I am
 working in a team and the members are not familiar with statistics.The
 apply Analysis of ANCOVA on around 50 continuous variables. They do the separate
 analysis for each dependent variable (each of these 50 variables) and
 they only apply ANCOVA on all models without checking the assumptions
 and etc.

Each time that I explain to them that we need to check the
 assumptions and also make sure that we have the linear relationship
 between variables they do not accept that and they mention that we
 need to just apply linear models because in the case of nonlinearity
 we cannot explain the results to the audience. Also, they do not want
 to use different Box-Cox transformation, they want to apply exactly
 the same model on. I was wondering if this way of analysis make sense?

The model is $y_i=\text{ sex }+\text{ age }+ \text{ race } (i=1,..,50)$ and race is a categorical variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's wrong.  It generates wrong results. If you can, I would leave the team.  They are, sooner or later, going to do something really stupid and, if you are on the team, you might get part of the blame.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your reply. They want to compare the means of each dependent variable among the levels of a categorical variable. This is the purpose of all their projects. They believe that just the linear models would be easy to interpret. So I thought maybe I should apply Robust ANCOVA on all their analysis as this method is not sensitive to the violation of assumptions. Is this a good idea?

Comment: It could be.  I like Quantile Regression a lot, too.